# how to write data to existing plistfile?

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone

how can i write new data existing plist file ?

sample code from my app

```
-(NSString *)mypath { 

    NSArray *path =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *myfilename = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [myfilename stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydata.plist"];

}
[myarray writeToFile:[self mypath] atomically:NO];
```

but it overwriting the existing file

is there any chance  that i can edit existing file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to "edit" the existing file, you will have to initialize your array from the plist file, then edit the array. You can then save the array to the same location again.

Example:

```
NSMutableArray *myarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self mypath]];
//Perform changes to myarray. e.g. [myarray removeObjectAtIndex:...];
[myarray writeToFile:[self mypath] atomically:NO];
```